# Displaying a PDF file into UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I want to display a pdf file in a `UIWebView`. My PDF is coming from a web service and I am able to store it in a documents directory successfully. But when I try to load the PDF url into my `UIWebView`, it displays a blank webview. No errors are reported.

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be going wrong here or how I can better debug this problem?

Comment: How are you trying to load the pdf into UIWebView? Add some code pls..

Comment: Can you post some code where you load the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//Considering your pdf is stored in documents directory with name as "pdfFileName"

NSString *pdfPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mynewDocument.pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Use debugger to check the contents of `url`. It should point to the exact `pdf` location.
Also, You can use `UIWebView`'s delegate methods:-

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: Hi shri , I write the same code what you write in above. But still i am not able to display pdf into UIwebview. If I add the any other pdf file into resource folder that works fine, only problem is when I want to display generated pdf file after base64 decoding to the UIwebview . It shows blank page I dont why it happens is that pdf is not saved properly or because of another thing that problem occurs. Please reply thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok. Three things
1)When you say you are able to save the file in Documents Directory, Did u actually check the documents directory(of simulator because its easier to check) and ensure that the file is stored correctly and you are able to open and read it???

2)Can you post some code where you are saving it onto documents directory and using base64 decoding

3)Also, what's the content of url? The pdf name should match exactly with the one saved in documnets directory

Comment: ya I am able to check it in document directory. I also able to open and read it. And the path which is generated of URL is this file://localhost/Users/pareshkarnawat/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/15FEA076-2600-4C74-8C44-137A6DA48EB7/Documents/mynewDocument.pdf . Also I am opening this pdf into uiwbview  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalUrlPath];
    [pdfContent writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [pdfView loadRequest:urlRequest];

Comment: I tried the same code locally and its working. Have you added .pdf extension to the file in your code? Also, why are you using  [pdfContent writeToURL:url atomically:YES];??? 

If you are getting this pdf from webservice, I recommend loading the webview after some time because if the pdf is huge, It might happen that the loadRequest is called earlier than the pdf is written to documents directory(just a guess). To check this, copy the pdf manually to documents directory from finder and then run the application.

Comment: Hey Shri still i am struggling with the pdf. I am trying to load the generated pdf into UIwebview but it is not opening in to that. Instead of that if I use another pdf manually it works fine. I guess that while storing pdf it may not getting save correctly. Do you have code how to save NSData to the file as extension pdf and save it into directory. So that afterwords I can get that pdf to show it in UIWebview. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: Add some code where you are saving the pdf to documents directory.. To write NSData to documents directory you could use  writeToFile:atomically:

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES );
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *urlPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mynewDocument"];
NSString *finalUrlPath = [urlPath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalUrlPath];
[pdfContent writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
pdfView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
[pdfView loadRequest:urlReq];

Comment: hey shri is that I am doing wrong decoding and not able to save proper pdf file into document directory. Because when I am trying to load that generated pdf from documents directory I am getting only blank webview. If possible give me the right base64 decoding and file saving as a pdf code Thanx

Comment: Whats in your "pdfContent" and from where are you setting its value? Post that code also. When you say your pdf is coming from webservice, in which format is it coming? If possible, also post the webservice here.

Comment: pdfconent is NSData object.I am getting my base 64 decoded string that I am converting into NSdata to convert it into file to save as a pdf into Document Directory.  NSData *b64DecData = [Base64 decode:pdfString]; [self DisplayPdf:b64DecData];

Comment: -(void)DisplayPdf:(NSData *)pdfContent{NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES );NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];NSString *urlPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myNewDocument.pdf"];
[pdfContent writeToFile:urlPath atomically:YES];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlPath];NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];pdfView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
[pdfView loadRequest:urlRequest];}

Comment: It seems the problem is with decoding. Can you post the webservice which you are caling?

Comment: NSString *soapMessage =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
       "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
       "<soap:Body>\n"
                            "<GetPDFByInvoicepdfID xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
       "<invoicepdfID>%@</invoicepdfID>"
       "</GetPDFByInvoicepdfID>\n"
       "</soap:Body>\n"
       "</soap:Envelope>\n",pdfIDstr];

Comment: [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Hi did you find the answer finally????Because am also getting the same issue now....Can you share with me if you know the answer..